# value.match is undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I am just here to see if anyone knows what may be going on here in my React application. So I am doing some validation in my input field and it has to do with some numbers. I am doing the validation here:

```
  const handleAmount = (value) => {
    const formattedInput = value.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,20}/);
    const minimumPurchase = 5;
    if (Number(formattedInput) < Number(minimumPurchase)) {
      setIsInvalidAmount(true);
    } else {
      setIsInvalidAmount(false);
    }
    setAmount(formattedInput);
  };
```

And here is where the handler is being attached to:

```
          <TextField
            className={classes.textField}
            type="number"
            onChange={e => handleAmount(e.target.value)}
            value={amount}
            error={isInvalidAmount} />
```

I also have a button to autofill the amount of items to purchase:

```
  function autoFillAmountTotal(selectedItem) {
    if (availableBalance.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,8}/) != null) {
      const netBalance = selectedItem.amountOfItems - selectedItems.backlogged;
      setAmount(netBalance);

      // This causes an error with value.match from the handleAmount function
      handleAmount(netBalance);

      // This renders fine, but I need it to do the calculation before passing value
      handleAmount(selectedItem.amountOfItems);
    }
  }

  function getAvailableText() {
    if (selectedItem) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className={classes.availableAmount}>(Number of items to buy: <Link className={classes.available} variant="text" onClick={() => autoFillAmountTotal(selectedItem.amountOfItems - selectedItem.backlogged)}>{items.amountOfItems}</Link>)</div>
        </React.Fragment>
```

);
}

This autofilled amount needs to do some validation, and it needs to have an onChange event, so I put the handleAmount function(which is an onChange handler attached to textfield) inside the autofill function. Otherwise, there wouldn't be any validation done in there.

The issue is when I try to pass an amount inside after calculation in the handleAmount() function when it is called inside another function, it gives an error.

Comment: Doesn't value.match return an array? Please check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match. So I would write your if statements a bit differently. Like `availableBalance.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,8}/).length`. But this would be just cosmetic, I think. Let me analyse this...

Answer (score -1):

Well, `String.prototype.match()` accepts only strings. You may convert your value into a string or check it with basic if statements like:

```
if (value > 0 && value < 20) {
    ...
}
```

Sorry, I'm not the RegEx expert, but from what I can see is that you check your value if it's a number and that it is between 0 and 20.

UPDATE:

I refactored the code a bit and added comments, where I didn't know where certain values come from.

```
function autoFillAmountTotal(selectedItem) {
    // I don't know where the value availableBalance comes from
    // I guess from a state. Please check if it is a string or convert it to one, like I show in solution number 1.
    if ((availableBalance.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,8}/)||[]).length) {
      const netBalance = selectedItem.amountOfItems - 
      selectedItems.backlogged;
      setAmount(netBalance);

      // This causes an error with value.match from the handleAmount function
      handleAmount(netBalance);

      // This renders fine, but I need it to do the calculation before passing value
      handleAmount(selectedItem.amountOfItems);
    }
}
```

And then your handleAmount function solution number 1:

```
const handleAmount = (value) => {
    // convert your value to a string before you match it with a regEx
    const valueString = value.toString();
    const formattedInput = valueString.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,20}/);
    const minimumPurchase = 5;
    if (Number(formattedInput) < Number(minimumPurchase)) {
      setIsInvalidAmount(true);
    } else {
      setIsInvalidAmount(false);
    }
    setAmount(formattedInput);
};
```

Here your handleAmount function preferred solution number 2. Your RegEx checks if you have any float number with at most 20 followed points after the decimal point.

```
// somewhere on top of your document, put your constants preferably like this
const MINIMUM_PURCHASE = 5; 

const handleAmount = (value) => {
     // convert float to number without decimals. 
     // I guess, this is not even needed, because the selectedItem value should be already a number without decimals
    const formattedInput = Number(Math.floor(value)); 

    if (formattedInput < MINIMUM_PURCHASE) {
      setIsInvalidAmount(true);
    } else {
      setIsInvalidAmount(false);
    }
    setAmount(formattedInput);
};
```